# Python Работа с JSON в MySQL Стоит ли?

Tags: python, mysql, json

Как происходит процесс добавления/извлечения JSON данных из MySQL? Достаточно ли их просто записывать в виде строки, а потом извлекать, превращать в словарь и также записывать, только в обратном порядке?

Уместно ли вообще использовать MySQL если я собираюсь записывать и извлекать json в python?

Comment: Может быть и достаточно, но в MySQL есть специальный тип столбца для json

Comment: если нужно хранить только json, то я бы обратил внимание на nosql базы данных